# "TypeError: this.inject is not a function" when using jQuery with prototype.js

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I am using jQuery with prototype. and I am using jQuery.noConflict() to remove confliction with prototype. and it is working fine everywhere apart from one place.

Here I am getting one error in `prototype-1.6.0.3.js`

> "TypeError: this.inject is not a function"

getting error in these lines in `prorotype-1.6.0.3.js`

```
flatten: function() {
    return this.inject([], function(array, value) {
      return array.concat(Object.isArray(value) ?
        value.flatten() : [value]);
    });
  },
```

---

It spoiled my whole day but I am not able to solve this issue.
Please reply me if anyone have solve this issue before. Thanks

Comment: You should create a minimal example that will reproduce that example, without that we can only tell you that there is something wrong with **your** code because the example on [Array#flatten](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Array/prototype/flatten/) works if prototype.js and jQuery are both loaded.

Comment: Are you able to upgrade to the latest PrototypeJS (1.7.2 April 2014) that should take care of your problem. If you are in Magento then you cant upgrade that far. `inject()` is defined on `Enumberable` so also check to make sure `Enumerable` exists. What browser is triggering this?

Comment: I have upgraded prototype-1.7.2,js. But still have same issue...

Comment: I found that jQuery is not a issue. Actually prototype is conflicting with mootools js. When I am removing mootools js. Its working fine. Do anyone have solution to remove confliction between prototype and mootools. like we have in jQuery ?

Comment: Why do you use three different libraries? It isn't even recommend to use two of them at the same time.